# How to group the data by the day-month parts of the Date regardless of the year part?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a big dataframe whose its first 5 rows are:

```
       Date     Element     Data_Value
0   2010-11-25    TMIN         228
1   2014-08-03    TMAX         332
2   2012-04-03    TMAX         311
3   2009-11-14    TMAX         294
4   2011-10-20    TMIN         220
```

Those data are daily measurements of the minimum and maximum temperature (TMIN
 & TMAX) over the period 2005-2014 and there are several TMIN and TMAX for the same date (they are measurements from different equipment).

I need the minimum temperature

I need to make a dataframe with the following columns:
column 1: the date but in day and months (the year is not important)
column 2: The minimum value of the temperature (Data_Value) for a given day-month measured in the period mentioned above, i.e. for the 31 of December take the minimum Data_Value from all the Data_Value of the years. I need to make this for every single day-month.
column 3: This columns is similar to the previous one but instead of minimum values here I need the maximum ones.

so, the dataframe that I am looking for should be something like this:

```
Date      TMIN        TMAX
11-25      151        300
12-31      100        250
  .         .          .
  .         .          .
```

I was using groupby:

```
per_day = df.Date.dt.to_period("D")
g_day = df.groupby(per_day)
```

Here I can use `g_day.min()` and `g_day.max()` so I am taking the min and max values for the data of the same day, and here is where I am stuck, I need only do the same but for the years (take the min and max of the same pair day-month for all the years)

The data with I am working on can be found here: https://hub.coursera-notebooks.org/user/gksihrbikiyeqyhpwaxvrt/edit/data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d25/e696f3d79c6a540c6e6467eba0e59a9308653e877a41e5825451599f.csv

Comment: Can you provide a better example? It is a bit unclear from your input and output data to understand what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my own, but the answer is a mess:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d25/e696f3d79c6a540c6e6467eba0e59a9308653e877a41e5825451599f.csv')
    data.drop(labels=['ID','Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5','Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
    data.sort_values(by='Date',inplace=True)

    per_day = data.Date.dt.to_period("D")
    g_day = data.groupby(per_day)
    T_min = g_day.min()
    T_max = g_day.max()
    T_min['Date'] = (T_min['Date']).astype('str').str.split('-').str.get(0)
    T_max['Date'] = (T_max['Date']).astype('str').str.split('-').str.get(0)

    df_min = pd.DataFrame()
    df_max = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in T_min['Date'].unique():
        df_min[i] = T_min[T_min['Date'] == i]['Data_Value'].reset_index(drop=True)
        df_max[i] = T_max[T_max['Date'] == i]['Data_Value'].reset_index(drop=True)

    min_2015 = df_min['2015']
    max_2015 = df_max['2015']
    df_min.drop(labels='2015',axis=1,inplace=True)
    df_max.drop(labels='2015',axis=1,inplace=True)
    df_min['min'] = df_min.min(axis=1)
    df_max['max'] = df_max.max(axis=1)
```